# How to handle images offline in a PWA share target?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I can register my Progressive Web App as a [share target for images](https://wicg.github.io/web-share-target/level-2/#example-5-manifest-webmanifest) ([supported from Chrome Android 76](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6124071381106688)):

```js
"share_target": {
    "action": "/share-target",
    "method": "POST",
    "enctype": "multipart/form-data",
    "params": {
      "files": [
        {
          "name": "myImage",
          "accept": ["image/jpeg", "image/png"]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I can then intercept attempts to share images to the app in a service worker:

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', e => {
  if (e.request.method === 'POST' && e.request.url.endsWith('/share-target')) {
    // todo
  }
})
```

How would I display the shared image in my offline PWA?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few different steps to take here.

I put together a working example at https://web-share-offline.glitch.me/, with the source at https://glitch.com/edit/#!/web-share-offline

#### Ensure your web app works offline

This is a prerequisite, and I accomplished it by generating a service worker that would precache my HTML, JS, and CSS using [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/).

The JS that runs when the home page is loaded uses the Cache Storage API to read a list of image URLs that have been cached, to creates `<img>` elements on the page corresponding to each one.

#### Create a share target handler that will cache images

I also used Workbox for this, but it's a bit more involved. The salient points are:

- Make sure that you intercept `POST` requests for the configured share target URL.
- It's up to you to read in the body of the shared images and to write them to your local cache using the Cache Storage API.
- After you save the shared image to cache, it's a good idea to respond to the `POST` with a [`HTTP 303` redirected response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303), so that the browser will display the actual home page for your web app.

Here's the Workbox configuration code that I used to handle this:

```
const shareTargetHandler = async ({event}) => {
  const formData = await event.request.formData();
  const cache = await caches.open('images');

  await cache.put(
      // TODO: Come up with a more meaningful cache key.
      `/images/${Date.now()}`,
      // TODO: Get more meaningful metadata and use it
      // to construct the response.
      new Response(formData.get('image'))
  );

  // After the POST succeeds, redirect to the main page.
  return Response.redirect('/', 303);
};

module.exports = {
  // ... other Workbox config ...
  runtimeCaching: [{
    // Create a 'fake' route to handle the incoming POST.
    urlPattern: '/share-target',
    method: 'POST',
    handler: shareTargetHandler,
  }, {
    // Create a route to serve the cached images.
    urlPattern: new RegExp('/images/\\d+'),
    handler: 'CacheOnly',
    options: {
      cacheName: 'images',
    },
  }],
};
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer (and well deserving of the bounty!). The demo app works great on a Pixel phone and an Oppo phone that we tested, however for some reason doesn't seem to work on Samsung phones - we tested it on many Samsung phones with Chrome 76 but after installing to the home screen it never appeared in the share sheet when sharing an image - any idea why?

Comment: That's odd to hear—it sounds like you tested with multiple Samsung devices, but could you let me know what the newest device was that exhibited those symptoms, along with the version of Android OS that it's using? (I don't have a Samsung device handy right now to confirm.)

Comment: Our main Samsung testing device is a Samsung Galaxy S7, model number SM-G930F, running Android 7.0 and Chrome 76.0.3809.132. We also tested it on a number of more recent phones in a Samsung store, such as the Note 10 and S9, but could not get it working on any Samsung device.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll try to dig up a device, but at the same time, could I ask you to post those details and the repro steps at http://crbug.com/new?

Comment: To make it work on my Samsung I set the icon url to local files and set start_url to index.html
The App can them be instaled and visible. But it dont' work: when I share an image, the App try to open a folder name /share-target on my Web server so not "offline". And of course, this fail. I've add other example from Google, and result is the same... :/

Comment: Dont' know if it came from the fact I use a Samsung but it doesnt' work. As previsouly said, the app try to call my web server rather than saving in cache. If on Manifest I set "action": "share_target.php" I can see my php code is called when I share img to the app. But this call send nothing. A file_get_content on php://input read nothing and a loop againts post variable show nothing came from the phone. I'll suggest Jeff to make a very (very!) small code to test and try to see what is the problem.

Comment: Brilliant example! Works well with my app, but only if the app was running recently. More here in a separate issue, maybe related to workbox and redirecting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64679799/offline-share-target-handler-with-workbox-ony-works-if-pwa-recently-active