# Recover full path of an image in Angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript, progressive-web-apps, indexeddb

I'm building an application in **Angular 8** with **PWA**. It is a Travel Refund where the user sends pictures of his invoices through the app. Then saves in a database when online and if the user is offline, the app saves in **IndexedDb**. When online again, the app look for pending uploads in **IDB** and then does. I don't want to save the image itself 'cause **IDB** has a limit cache memory in some browsers, so I chose to save the *image path* so that the application could find it later.

That's when my problem appears, I try to save in **IDB** the image **full path** to get it later when online, but some browsers don't allow it for *security* reasons. So, there is another way to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57917599/how-to-handle-images-offline-in-a-pwa-share-target

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by talhature it is not possible to save the URL. This is also due to security reasons, a website should not be able to read the file system.

You can retrieve a file like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)"/>
```

```
public files: any[];

contructor() { this.files = []; }

onFileChanged(event: any) {
  this.files = event.target.files;
  this.files.forEach(file => setData(file));
}
```

If you are able to persist the blobs to localstorage you can use online and offline events to distinguish:

```
 let online = window.navigator.onLine;

 function handleOnline() {
   const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
   
   // post to backend

   localSorage.setItem('data', null);
   online = true;
 }

 function setData(data) {
   if (online) {
     
   // post to backend
   
   } else {
      localSorage.setItem('data', JSON.parse(data))
   }
 }

 window.addEventListener('online',  handleOnline);
 window.addEventListener('offline', () => online = false);
```